# RegEx for matching special chars no spaces or newlines

Tags: c#, regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-greedy

I have a string and want to use regex to match all the chars, but no spaces.

I tried to replace all the spaces with nothing, using:

```
Regex.Replace(seller, @"[A-z](.+)", m => m.Groups[1].Value);

//rating
var betyg = Regex.Replace(seller, @"[A-z](.+)", m => m.Groups[1].Value);`
```

I expect the output of

```
"Iris-presenter | 5"
```

but, the output is

```
"Iris-presenter"
```

seen in this also seen in this [demo](https://regexr.com/4dcvg).

The string is:

```
<spaces>Iris-presenter
<spaces>|
<spaces>5
```

Comment: Sorry, what is your input exactly?

Comment: Disregarding your explanation, it seems you want to turn multiple spaces and new lines into one space. i think you need to be a little more specific

Comment: You can see the input in the demo. You are exactly right

Comment: You could replace `\s+` which matches one or more [whitespaces](https://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) and replace them with ` ` (one whitespace). FInally `.Trim()` the string

Comment: That worked like a sharm. now i have [this](https://regexr.com/4ddrt). I need to match the "Points :"

Comment: You are **not** replacing spaces with nothing. You are matching a char in `[A-z]` and what follows it and replacing them with that following part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used `(\s(.*?))` for it to work. This removes all spaces and new lines seen [here](https://regexr.com/4dqua)

Answer (score 0):

Great question! I'm not quite sure, if this would be what you might be looking for. [This expression](https://regex101.com/r/wuVVcV/1) however matches your input string:

```
^((?!\s|\n).)*
```

[image]

#### Graph

The graph shows how it might work:

[image]

#### Edit

Based on [revo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1020526/revo)'s advice, the expression can be much simplified, because

> `^((?!\s|\n).)*` is equal to `^((?!\s).)*` and both are equal to `^\S*`.

[image]

Comment: FYI `^((?!\s|\n).)*` is equal to `^((?!\s).)*` and both are equal to `^\S*`.